# Why can't I use Inactive[D] in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, hold

I have a 2D rectangular domain with `-L/2 < x < L/2` and `0 < y < D0`, which is divided into two parts, with a sinusoidal curve `y == 1 + δ Cos[2 Pi x/L]` separating the two.

I want to solve Laplace equation `D[κ[x, y] D[T[x, y], x], x] + D[κ[x, y] D[T[x, y], y], y] == 0`, where `κ[x, y]` takes different values in the two regions (equals `1` below the curve, and `0.2422` above the curve). After copying some codes in StackExchange, I have the following codes which I think give the right answer:

```
D0 = 3;
k = 0.2422;
L = 3;
δ = 0.2;
sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
   Div][-If[y <= 1 - δ Cos[2 π x/L], 1, 
     k].Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
PeriodicBoundaryCondition[T[x, y], x == -L/2, 
 TranslationTransform[{L, 0}]],
DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 1 + δ Cos[2 π x/L], 
 y == 0 && -L/2 < x < L/2],
DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 0, y == D0 && -L/2 < x < L/2]},
   T, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, 0, D0}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {T -> 2}, 
 "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}, 
 "IntegrationOrder" -> 5}];
Show[ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, 0, D0}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> 20],
 Plot[1 - δ Cos[2 π x/L], {x, -L/2, L/2}]]
```

Now I want to solve a slightly different equation `D[κ[x, y] D[T[x, y], x], x] + epsilon^2 D[κ[x, y] D[T[x, y], y], y] == 0`. This is basically Laplace equation where the two spatial coordinates are scaled differently, and I want to study the effect of ignoring the second term with `epsilon^2` in my analytical work.

I try to define the equation differently as `Inactive[D][-If[y <= 1-δ Cos[2 π x/L], 1, k] Inactive[D][T[x, y], {x}], {x}] + (epsilon^2) Inactive[D][-If[y <= 1-δ Cos[2 π x/L], 1, k] Inactive[D][T[x, y], {y}], {y}] == 0`

But it gives an error `NDSolveValue::derivs: No derivatives of dependent variables were found in the equations. NDSolveValue is designed to solve differential or differential algebraic equations. Use NSolve or FindRoot to numerically solve algebraic equations.`

What's the problem? In fact, I don't think I fully understand the use of `Inactive`. What's the best way to define the PDE (or the domain) in this case?

Comment: Where's the `epsilon` in the new PDE? Have you read the "Formal Partial Differential Equations" section in the document page `FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview`?

Comment: @xzczd just edited. I basically don't understand why the way I write the equation (splitting it into the x and y derivatives instead of using `grad` and  `div`) doesn't work.

Comment: I think this is a good question. My guess is `Inactive` is only for building the "formal PDE", but it's not explicitly mentioned in the document. Let's wait for user21's clarification :) .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The coefficient you give for the diffusion operator is a scalar but you can give a matrix of coefficients. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
D0 = 3;
k = 0.2422;
L = 3;
δ = 0.2;
epsilon = 10^-1;
```

Note how the `coeff` now returns a matrix of coefficients:

```
coeff = If[
   y <= 1 - δ Cos[2 π x/L], -{{1, 0}, {0, 
      epsilon^2*1}}, -{{k, 0}, {0, epsilon^2*k}}];
```

Well just plug that in:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[Div][
      coeff.Inactive[Grad][T[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0, 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[T[x, y], x == -L/2, 
     TranslationTransform[{L, 0}]], 
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 1 + δ Cos[2 π x/L], 
     y == 0 && -L/2 < x < L/2], 
    DirichletCondition[T[x, y] == 0, y == D0 && -L/2 < x < L/2]}, 
   T, {x, -L/2, L/2}, {y, 0, D0}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}}];
```

As a side note, for single equations you never need to specify "InterpolationOrder"; that is only relevant for coupled PDE where you want to interpolate some of the dependent variables not at the highest level.

The new in version 12.1 [HeatTransfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html) has a section on [isotropic, orthotropic and anisotropic diffusion](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html#189725639) that explain the concepts and implementation more.

Comment: Any comment on the `Inactive[D]` part?

Comment: @xzczd, basically because it is not implemented. You should be able to do everything with Inactive[Div] and Inactive[Grad], no?

Comment: Yeah, but `Inactive[D]` will make coding more flexible, right? :) I think the more important part is, this isn't explicitly documented. Do you mean currently only `Inactive[Div]` and `Inactive[Grad]` are supported by `FiniteElement` method of  `NDSolve`?

Comment: @xzczd, yes only Inactive Div/Grad (for differential operators) are supported. And, yes, it might make sense to mention that in the documentation.

Comment: @xzczd, I tried to clarify this in the documentation and this should be in 12.1.1. Thanks.

Comment: I just notice `Inactive[Times]` and `Inactive[Plus]` are also supported (Mentioned in _Finite Element Usage Tips_). Is there a full summary about when `Inactive` can be used for FEM?

Comment: @xzczd, it's just the operators that are needed to represent FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice#1365985109, so we have Div, Grad, Dot, Times and Plus.